# how to disable tcp_resets_received from netdata

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, ip, tcp

I'm receiving TCP reset emails from netdata, how would I disable the resets from happening on my linux GCP Instance?

Linux: 20.04
Provider: GCP

I've tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404552/6651840) but it doesnt seem to be working.

emails received below...

[image]

[image]

Comment: The link you gave about dropping INVALID state is a very good point that should always be done when REJECT rules are also used (or "good" connections could be randomly terminated). But you shouldn't have people need to read links to understand the question: this should be included in the question. Beside this, you don't give any information that can help answer the question. Do you suspect your firewall rules? Do you suspect your application is crashing? Are there facts to suspect one case or the other etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you identified what is the source of these resets? Is it generated on your host or by the peer and also which application?

You can see some of these details on the netdata charts.

If the behaviour is expected and from time to time certain tcp sockets are meant to be reset, you can modify your alerts on netdata to set a different threshold or even disable the notifications:
https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/configure/common-changes

Answer (score 1):

Also ran into this, it looks like this is caused by port scans in our case.

I disabled the alert by running:
`sudo /etc/netdata/edit-config health.d/tcp_resets.conf`

This command is also at the end of the notification email, including the linenumber where the alert is located in that file. Change `to:` from `sysadmin` to `silent`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but already did that.

Comment: thanks for the answer but already did that.